# Can't center div on screen on top of page content after setting "display: block" on function using z-index?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently building a blackjack game and was using alerts to let the player know they won. I eventually swapped over to using animate.css to get a simple "you won" and "you lost" message to appear on the screen after the logic finds a winner.

I do this by having a function popup() that runs each time a win or loss parameter is met within if elses, and sets the display to "block". At first, I had this animation div between the 2 sides of the game board ( the player and dealer side, each with a flex property), but hated the fact that once the div appears on the function running, it pushes the player side down. To fix this, I thought I could simply put a z-index to the animation so that it would just appear to overlap.

At first this wasnt working, but then I moved the div that holds my animation outside of the main container (which is a flex container), which now works and stops any content from being pushed down... but I am having issues with the positioning.

I am trying to position the div in the center of the screen to act as a modal or pop-up, and I want to add a interval the div to allow me to close the whole container when a timer runs out ( and thus remove the animation from the screen and allowing the player to choose the "new game" button ).

After trying various things, I can either...

1. get it to be centered ( H and V ), but pushing content ( meaning z index isnt working, which is where I started )
2. get it to have z-index and appear above everything else, and even get it to be centered in the screen, but unable to get its sizing to work properly and there is this weird UI glitch where the scrollbar will appear and then disappear ( as if the screen size is getting bigger when the animation appears, which is weird because the animation has a z-index of 2, so why would it make the screen bigger? ).

Sorry if this is a little hard to follow, but the TLDR is that I am unable to get my animation div to appear horizontally and vertically centered without some issue.

Here is some of my code:

```
  <h1 class="animated jackInTheBox" id="youWin"></h1>



 .jackInTheBox {
 animation-duration: 4s;
 animation-delay: 0s;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 margin: auto;
 font-size: 32px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 margin: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 display: none;
 background-color: teal;
```

}

This animation div sits inside of the main container div, at the very top

```
   .mainContainer {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   margin: auto;
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
  }
```

Part of me thinks that this would be better to do with a modal, but I would still like to see where I am going wrong. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your  jack in the box class to position fixed with

```
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -100px;
```

Like you mentioned, this is  a little hard to follow without being able to see more code of what you have. Do you think you could add this as a jsfiddle/codepen that contains all of your code? I get a feeling there may be something more to the issue than what you have placed.

This link may also help https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

Answer (score 0):

If parent container has `position: relative` and child has `position: absolute` then you can set children with following properties to move it in the middle of parent's horizontal and vertical axis:

```
 .jackInTheBox {
 animation-duration: 4s;
 animation-delay: 0s;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 font-size: 32px;
 z-index: 2;
 text-align: center;
 display: none;
 background-color: teal;

 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Last four lines let you make it:

`position: absolute;` sets child in relation to parent's up, left corner (if parent has `position: relative`)

`top: 50%;` moves child to the center of screen (child's top border will be in the middle of screen horizontal axis)

`left: 50%;` moves child to the center of screen (child's left border will be in the middle of screen vertical axis)

`transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` makes child move 50% of its width into left and 50% of its height into top making it centered perfectly as you need

After doing this you don't need to set `width` neither `max-width`, as `<h1>` markup is a block element and it takes 100% of parent width automatically.

Additional, you don't have to make your parent element has `display: relative` to get the same effect. Child will use then screen original properties to set position.